# OpenWRT WPA2-Enterprise & RADIUS - config is not applied

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, openwrt, radius, wpa2

i'm currently using OpenWrt Backfire 10.03 on an Asus WL-500G Premium v1.
Scenario is like that: AP should connect to a RADIUS server via wired ethernet and perform authentication requests.

I'm running into problems when i try to apply the new configuration file.
output of /etc/config/wireless (obv. not production mode)

```
config 'wifi-device' 'radio0'
        option 'type' 'mac80211'
        option 'channel' '5'
        option 'macaddr' '00:1f:c6:51:34:dc'
        option 'hwmode' '11g'
        option 'disabled' '0'

config 'wifi-iface'
        option 'device' 'radio0'
        option 'network' 'lan'
        option 'mode' 'ap'
        option 'ssid' 'OpenWrt'
        option 'encryption' 'wpa2'
        #RADIUS Server
        option 'auth_server' '192.168.1.249'
        option 'auth_secret' 'test123'
        option 'acct_server' '192.168.1.249'
        option 'acct_secret' 'test123'
```

performing uci show wireless sets the configuration parameters as expected

```
wireless.radio0=wifi-device
wireless.radio0.type=mac80211
wireless.radio0.channel=5
wireless.radio0.macaddr=00:1f:c6:51:34:dc
wireless.radio0.hwmode=11g
wireless.radio0.disabled=0
wireless.@wifi-iface[0]=wifi-iface
wireless.@wifi-iface[0].device=radio0
wireless.@wifi-iface[0].network=lan
wireless.@wifi-iface[0].mode=ap
wireless.@wifi-iface[0].ssid=OpenWrt
wireless.@wifi-iface[0].encryption=wpa2
wireless.@wifi-iface[0].auth_server=192.168.1.249
wireless.@wifi-iface[0].auth_secret=test123
wireless.@wifi-iface[0].acct_server=192.168.1.249
wireless.@wifi-iface[0].acct_secret=test123
```

But when i try to bring the wifi back up errors are thrown

```
root@OpenWrt:/etc/config# wifi down && sleep 5 && wifi
Configuration file: /var/run/hostapd-phy0.conf
Line 46: unknown configuration item 'auth_server_addr'
Line 47: unknown configuration item 'auth_server_port'
Line 48: unknown configuration item 'auth_server_shared_secret'
Line 51: unknown configuration item 'radius_acct_interim_interval'
Invalid IEEE 802.1X configuration (no EAP authenticator configured).
5 errors found in configuration file '/var/run/hostapd-phy0.conf'
Failed to start hostapd for phy0
```

Why isn't the router using the /etc/config/wireless file? I tried to restart it with no success

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've managed it. The problem was that the wpad-mini package was installed but it does not support WPA2-Enterprise security. It was nescessary to perform
`opkg update
 opkg remove wpad-mini
 opkg install wpad`

Now everything is working as intended!